# ClearCase Version Tree Browser SendTo context menu subfolders

Tags: clearcase

I want to group the commands in my SendTo Windows XP folder into different subfolders.
Creating a subdirectories in the SendTo folder and putting shortcuts in these subfolders works fine for Windows Explorer. But for ClearCase 7.0.1 Version Tree the right click SendTo context menu does not show the shortcuts in the subfolders.

Has anyone found a way to make this work - or does it work in a later release of ClearCase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7.0.1 has always had issues with the SendTo menu.
As an example, see [this thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=192438) (on a different kind of issue).
(I suppose you are talking about ClearCase, not CC LT, and in 32bits, not [64bits which has its own set of issues](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=347915))

It should work better on 7.1.2, but i haven't fully tested the "SendTo" integration menu.